# Newcomer to JavaScript - stuck on first assignment

Tags: javascript

I have this super easy html and CCS file, with 1 big frame (div id = image) and 3 smaller frames (img class = preview). The task I am trying to accomplish using JavaScript for the first time (part of an online class, first JavaScript homework) is to make the text and the background image of the big frame adjust according to what I am hovering over the mouse. If I am hovering over one of the 3 smaller frames, their background image and their alt should appear in the big frame.

Using the code below, I was able to make the alt text appear, so that works fine. But I just cannot figure out the background image. I believe the beginning of the code is correct (document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = 'url()), but if I add one of the three src into the url, only that picture shows as I hardcoded it. The teacher mentioned that we should use a variable in the url(), but I just don't know which one.

What is my next step for this assignment?

```js
function upDate(element) {
  document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = element.alt;
  document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = 'url()';

}

function unDo(element) {

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}

#image {
  line-height: 650px;
  width: 575px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 650px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  background-color: #8e68ff;
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-size: 100%;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.preview {
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

img {
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  Hover over an image to display the alt text.
</div>

<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseleave="document.getElementById('image').innerHTML='Hover over an image';">

<img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseleave="document.getElementById('image').innerHTML='Hover over an image';">

<img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseleave="document.getElementById('image').innerHTML='Hover over an image';">
```

I tried to use all the classes, divs, if statements (changing the classes names), searching internet, W3school and other resources ... I could not find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Others has solved your issue already. However it is considered bad practise to use inline event handlers. Your course might be outdated.

Below I provided a working example how you can bind event handlers in javascript. This way you can attach more then 1 handler for each element event.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".preview").forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
    let element = event.target;
    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = element.alt;
    document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = `url(${element.src})`;
  });
  
  element.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = 'Hover over an image to display the alt text.';
    document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = '';
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}

#image {
  line-height: 650px;
  width: 575px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 650px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  background-color: #8e68ff;
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-size: 100%;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.preview {
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

img {
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  Hover over an image to display the alt text.
</div>

<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg">

<img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG">

<img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy">
```

Comment: Hi, that is super cool, though feels quite advanced. Trying to wrap my head around simple tasks; with time, the handlers will come handy for sure. Thank you for your time :-)

Comment: @KaterinaMala It's not really advanced. It's considered to goto way of binding event handlers these days. If there is anything you don't understand I can add some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the url using `element.src`. And, [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is how you can use a variable in a string in js.

```js
function upDate(element) {
  document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = element.alt;
  document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = `url(${element.src})`;
}

function unDo(element) {

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}

#image {
  line-height: 650px;
  width: 575px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 650px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  background-color: #8e68ff;
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-size: 100%;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.preview {
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

img {
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  Hover over an image to display the alt text.
</div>

<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseleave="document.getElementById('image').innerHTML='Hover over an image';">

<img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseleave="document.getElementById('image').innerHTML='Hover over an image';">

<img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseleave="document.getElementById('image').innerHTML='Hover over an image';">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I knew template literals, it's just i still do not understand why i have to use them in the first place ... why i could not just used 'url(element.src)' and that's it?

Comment: `url(element.src)` Will result in an url to `element.src`.  `url(${element.src})` will result in an url to the value of of the `src` attribute which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path, you just need to get the `src` of the image.

```
function upDate(element) {
  const imgSrc = element.src; // get image src
  document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = element.alt;
  document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = `url(${imgSrc})`;

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, love the 'just' as that was the part that caused my headaches :) It seems pretty straightforward and i did try it with element.src but it did not work because i did not concatenate it ... :(

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to set the background image URL to an empty string in the upDate function:

```
document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = 'url()';
```

This line should have dynamically set the background image URL based on the src attribute of the hovered element. To achieve this, you need to concatenate the URL string with the element.src:

```
document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + element.src + ')';
```

Here's an updated version of your js code:

```
function upDate(element) {
  document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = element.alt;
  document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + element.src + ')';
}

function unDo() {
  document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = 'Hover over an image';
  document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = 'url("")';
}
```

upDate function takes the element and sets both the inner HTML and background image of the 'image' div. The element.src provides the URL of the hovered image.
unDo function resets the inner HTML and background image when the mouse leaves.

Also modify your HTML code as follow:

```
<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseleave="unDo()">
```

The onmouseleave attribute in your HTML to use the unDo function.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly the right answer the teacher was looking for (or the template literal version of it). However, i still dont understand why i could not use only 'url(element.src)' ... is it because the url requires to have '' in the bracket so you have to fill it with something? But then why to concatenate it? Anyway, this was exactly what i came for, so thank you :)

Comment: Your understanding is almost correct. The issue is with the syntax of the url() function in CSS. The url() function requires a valid URL enclosed in parentheses. if you were to use 'url(element.src)' directly, it would not be a valid URL because the url() function needs to have a string inside the parentheses. By concatenating the element.src with proper quotes, you are creating a valid URL string. 
In summary, the reason for concatenating is to ensure that you generate a valid URL string within the url() function, which is a requirement of the CSS syntax.